# ASP Page hosting an ASPX page rendered using XSLT

Tags: asp.net, xslt

I have a ASP page that has a DIV to load up ASPX page. The ASPX page is rendered using XSLT.

I am trying to solve some issue. How can I print the value of the following condition

```
        <tr class="table-data{(position() - 1) mod 2}">
        <td class='hier-data'>
            <xsl:if test="$EXPAND=APPLICATION_ID">
                <img src='/aaaa-images/common/arrow-sel.gif' alt='aaa' />
            </xsl:if>
            <a href='some.aspx?expand={APPLICATION_ID}'>
                <xsl:value-of select="APPLICATION_ID" />
           </a>
        </td>
        <td class='hier-data'>
            <xsl:value-of select="APPLICATION_NAME" />
        </td>
        <td class='hier-data'>
            <xsl:value-of select="DATE_CREATED" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <xsl:if test="$EXPAND=APPLICATION_ID">
        <xsl:call-template name="show_application_block" />
    </xsl:if>
```

I want to print the value of $EXPAND and see whether the condition is true. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put quotes around the value APPLICATION_ID, I believe for the comparison to work.

To output the value, just use xsl:value-Of element.

Simon

Comment: Thanks for the Xsl:Value-Of it works. For some reason it is false. I didn't understand your first comment about APPLICATION_ID.

Comment: I think you can ignore the first comment. I think I was wrong.